# Access Text Value lightning:inputField lookup

Tags: lightning, lightning-inputfield

Is there a way to access the text value of a lightning:inputField of lookup type? `.get('v.value')` returns the ID but I also want to retrieve the text value displayed within the lookup as well.

Comment: have you tried anything to get the text value? could you please include your code?

Comment: I don't see anything in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/specification) so suspect the answer is "no".

Comment: Assuming you can create your own custom lookup component and access the text value instead of accessing it through lightning:inputfield

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, for now, I am accepting that this is not viable so I built around it.

Comment: How can you get the ID of the inputField? Can you please provide the code snippet to get the ID? I am also trying to get the text value of the lightning:inputField of lookup type.

Comment: You will need to have an aura:id attribute on your input field. If you do, you can access the value of the component like any other. `component.find('Id of input').get('v.value')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, I gave up. Instead I added in some logic to retrieve the Name value from the Database based on the ID instead of continuing to spin my wheels. Hopefully in the future there will be some more attributes accessible to developers.